# wordpress - all URLs with no trailing slash redirect to include slash

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress, cms

Just started a new job and the company website is built on Wordpress. All URLs seem to have a trailing backslash for example https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/

We are moving to a different CMS and I want to get rid of these so the URLs are https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma

From what I can find out this was a requested redirect (I think maybe setup in Wordpress or AWS) where any URLs that dont have the backslash it adds a backslash.

looking at GSC I see a URL that is indexed without a backslash and the version that has the backslash is not indexed which is good from a duplicated content POV however looking at another page its the opposite (version with the backslash is indexed, non backslash isnt indexed)

Question: whats the best practice for moving CMS systems - ideally I dont want to have the backslashes and we are changing the URL slugs (not ideal but we need to)

so for the URL https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/ this is changing to https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/digital-learning-design I was going to setup a redirect from https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma/ to the new URL and then https://www.digitallearninginstitute.com/courses/professional-diploma (without backslash which gets redirected to the version WITH a redirect) change this to also redirect to the new URL.

Confusing I know but struggling to see the best way forward to make sure I can change the URLs, include redirects where needed without causing 404s.

Thanks

Comment: What CMS are you moving to?  These redirects need to be implemented in your new CMS.  WordPress is pretty much irrelevant once you have moved off of it.

Answer (score 1):

The method that worked fine for me is this :

Go to **Settings>>Permalinks>>Custom Structures**

Modify this **/%postname%/  to this /%postname%**. As you can see I removed the back slash trail at the end.

Save changes and clear the cache.

It will redirect automatically from back slashed url to non back slashed one

I hope this method will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to

- Use `.htaccess` (if you have access to it) and a redirect from `url\` to `url` for all your urls
- Have a `canonical` tag on each page pointing to the non slashes version.